# How to Accumulate/Collect/Sum list?

Tags: python, list, sum, collect

I'm really new using Python. I need to achieve the following.

I have a list

```
[
  ['1604201722','16/04/2017','22', 100.0, 10.0, 110.0],<br>
  ['1604201722','16/04/2017','22', 100.0, 10.0, 110.0],<br>
  ['1604201719','16/04/2017','19', 100.0, 10.0, 110.0]<br>
]
```

Line structure is

```
['     ID   ','    DATE  ','Hour',  CANT, CANT, CANT]
['1604201722','16/04/2017','22'  ,  100.0,10.0, 110.0]
```

I need to accumulate the values like this:

```
['1604201722','16/04/2017', '22' , 200.0, 20.0, 240.0]
['1604201719','16/04/2017', '19' , 100.0, 10.0, 110.0]
```

Comment: The best way to approach your problem is to convert the list into a `pandas` dataframe and then `groupby(["ID","DATE","Hour"]).cum()`. I leave the implementation details to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd
d = [
  ['1604201722','16/04/2017','22', 100.0, 10.0, 110.0],
  ['1604201722','16/04/2017','22', 100.0, 10.0, 110.0],
  ['1604201719','16/04/2017','19', 100.0, 10.0, 110.0]
]
df= pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['ID','DATE','HOUR','col1','col2','col3'])
print(df.groupby(['ID','DATE','HOUR']).sum())
```

Which will give this output:

```
ID         DATE       HOUR   col1  col2   col3                   
1604201719 16/04/2017 19    100.0  10.0  110.0
1604201722 16/04/2017 22    200.0  20.0  220.0
```